# CodeNarc supress JdbcREsultSetReference seems not working

Tags: groovy, codenarc

I have class similar to this one:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper
import java.sql.ResultSet

class DataMapper implements RowMapper<Data> {

    @Override
    @SupressWarnings('JdbcResultSetReference')
    Data mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        // get some values from resultSet and return desired Data
    }
}
```

This is one time script to migrate some data using groovy, so I want to suppress codenarc rule. In the `ruleSet` jdbc rules are included and I don't want to disable them, as they scanning all the project.

```
<ruleset xmlns="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0 
    http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd">

    <description>Static analysis rule set for Groovy sources</description>

    <!-- not related rules -->
    <ruleset-ref path='rulesets/jdbc.xml>
</ruleset>
```

I'm running static analysis within junit tests and get this error:

> ```
> [codenarc] File: com/example/migrate/DataMapper.groovy
> [codenarc]     Violation: Rule=JdbcResultSetReference P=2 Line=5 Msg=[Found reference to java.sql.ResultSet] Src=[import java.sql.ResultSet]
> [codenarc]     Violation: Rule=JdbcResultSetReference P=2 Line=5 Msg=[Found reference to java.sql.ResultSet] Src=[import java.sql.ResultSet]
> [codenarc] [CodeNarc (http://www.codenarc.org) v1.0]
> [codenarc] CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=2; p3=0) 5929ms
> ```

I tried moving `@SupressWarnings` to the class, but it still tells me that I'm violating the rule. So the question is: how to make that suppression to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately those rules look at import statements, and the @SuppressWarnings does not work on those.

One option is to disable that rule for your Mapper classes:
e.g. in your codenarc.properties:

```
    JdbcResultSetReference.doNotApplyToClassNames = *Mapper
```

or set that same property on the rule in your ruleset file.